# jQuery - expected identity or string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fårexpected identity or string on the "if (vContains (gMouseoverBox) == true) (" to
What is the reason for this?

```
var pProjectID = "static";
var gMouseoverBox = pProjectID + "_IF";
var arrBoxesNotMouseOvered = [];


function vContains(pName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrBoxesNotMouseOvered.length; i++) {
        if (arrBoxesNotMouseOvered[i] == pName) {
            arrBoxesNotMouseOvered[i] = null;

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



function PopulateTooltipSuccess(pResponse) {

    $('#' + gMouseoverBox).tooltip({

        if( vContains(gMouseoverBox) == true ) { 
            var elem = document.getElementById(gMouseoverBox); 
            var coord = { clientX: getElementLeft(gMouseoverBox)+1, clientY: getElementTop(gMouseoverBox)+1 };  //coordinates doesn't work perfecly in IE but does in Firefox

            $('#' + gMouseoverBox).simulate("mouseover", coord);
            $(this).oneTime(2000, function() {
                $('#' + gMouseoverBox).simulate("mouseout", coord);
                }); 
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what did you expect and what it turned out to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Maybe you could edit your question to be a bit clearer?

From your code, I can see the following:

1. Can you post the accompanying html? Do you have an element with id "static_IF" ?
2. Your arrBoxesNotMouseOvered is not populated. I'm guessing this happens elsewhere? Maybe we could see this code.
3. You never use the variable `elem` (and your doing a document.getElementById() instead of a jQuery selection
4. You do  $('#' + gMouseoverBox) and $(this). These should be the same.
5. $gMouseoverBox.tooltip({ - Do you mean to seocify an anonymous function here? See code below:

Suggest the following code instead:

```
function PopulateTooltipSuccess(pResponse) { 

    var $gMouseoverBox = $('#' + gMouseoverBox);
    $gMouseoverBox.tooltip(function(){ 
        if( vContains(gMouseoverBox) == true ) {  
            var coord = { 
                clientX: getElementLeft(gMouseoverBox)+1, 
                clientY: getElementTop(gMouseoverBox)+1 
            };  //coordinates doesn't work perfecly in IE but does in Firefox 

            $gMouseoverBox.simulate("mouseover", coord); 
            $gMouseoverBox.oneTime(2000, function() { 
                $gMouseoverBox.simulate("mouseout", coord); 
            });  
        } 
    });
}
```

Without understanding exactly what you're trying the achieve that's all I can say at the moment.